# How to save .nnet File in Neuroph Studio

Tags: neural-network

In NeurophStudio I created a neural network for image recognition but when i press the 'save' button under File menu (File->Save) then it just save it without informing me where it is saving it. Even the 'save as' button is disabled . How to find the file of .nnet extension . I have to use it in my java program .

Answer (score 0):

if you go into the project

Expand the neural network tab

then when you see your neural network name

highlight it

Ctrl and right click
a list of options come up

click on properties

another list comes up

in that list is  All FIles

to the right of that are three dots   ...

click on those dots
A new panel opens that gives you the exact location of the neural net and where it is stored

hope that helps

Phil